# How to put the name of a cell into another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In Google Sheets, is there a simpler way to put the name of a cell reference into another cell than this?

```
=concatenate(char(code("A")+COLUMN(D3)-1),row(D3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(D3),COLUMN(D3))
```

**Output:**

```
$D$3
```

Comment: That's a bit simpler. Next question: can I write a script function to do the same? As far as I can tell, if I put the cell name into the function argument list, what is passed to the function is the value of the cell, and what I need is a Range object.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
=address(3,4)
```

*if* the object is to return `$D$3`.